# PLSQL - Round Date to the nearest century?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is the output I am trying to get:

```
Number of slashes: 2
In 25 days it is: 19-FEB-15
The raw number is:
1.666666667E-01
The rounded number is: .17
Nearest Century: 01-JAN-01
```

I'm really not sure how to round "dDate25" to the nearest century?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
vFilePath VARCHAR2 (100) := 'c\Temp\ProcDB.mdf';
vFilePath1 VARCHAR2 (100);
nNumber16 FLOAT;
dDate25 DATE := SYSDATE+25;
BEGIN
vFilePath1 := REPLACE (vFILEPATH, '\');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of slashes:' || (LENGTH(vFilePath)-LENGTH(vFilePath1)));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In 25 days it is:' || to_char(dDate25, 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
nNumber16 := 1/6;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The raw number is: ' || to_char(nNumber16, '9.999999999EEEE'));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The rounded number is: ' || round(nNumber16, 2));

END;
```

Thanks,

Comment: please rethink the tags you chose for this question. You are messing around with MySQL, Oracle and SQlite all at once, which DBMS are you really on?

Comment: Oracle. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `TRUNC(date)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm) if you want to always 'round down' to the current century (so a date in 2051 gives 2001); or [the `ROUND(date)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions154.htm) if you want to round properly (so 2051 gives 2101). Either way, with the CC format mask to get the first day of the century:

```
SQL> select round(sysdate + 25, 'CC') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE+25,'C
-------------------
2001-01-01 00:00:00
```

So you can use:

```
ROUND(dDate25)
```

And you can then format that however you need; without any NLS assumptions:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nearest Century: '
  || TO_CHAR(ROUND(dDate25, 'CC'), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean **decade** instead of **century**, right? Otherwise your two end digits will always be "01" :-)

Corrected version (my previous one always returned 01, because it was rounding to the next century):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FLOOR(to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY')/10)*10,3,1) || 1 FROM dual
```

translated to your code:

```
decadeStart varchar2(10) := '01-JAN-' || SUBSTR(FLOOR(to_char(dDate25, 'YYYY')/10)*10,3,1) || 1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The decade starts with: ' || decadeStart);
```

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nearest Century: 01-JAN-' || (ROUND(to_char(dDate25, 'YYYY')/100)+1));` 

gets me this "**01-JAN-21**". Do you know how I can get it to display 01-JAN-**01**?

Thanks

Comment: Just updated my answer (without having access to an Oracle DB atm)

Comment: I'm getting these errors when I try to run the code with that line:

`Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 53:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBSTR'
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   dDate25   DATE;
   numYear   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   dDate25 := TO_DATE ('2016-01-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

   SELECT (ROUND (TO_CHAR (dDate25, 'YYYY') / 100, 0) * 100) + 1
     INTO numYear
     FROM DUAL;
     
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First year of the nearest century to ' || TO_CHAR(dDate25, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' is: ' || numYear);
     
   dDate25 := TO_DATE ('2116-01-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

   SELECT (ROUND (TO_CHAR (dDate25, 'YYYY') / 100, 0) * 100) + 1
     INTO numYear
     FROM DUAL;
   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First year of the nearest century to ' || TO_CHAR(dDate25, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' is: ' || numYear);

   dDate25 := TO_DATE ('2051-01-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
   
   SELECT (ROUND (TO_CHAR (dDate25, 'YYYY') / 100, 0) * 100) + 1
     INTO numYear
     FROM DUAL;
   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First year of the nearest century to ' || TO_CHAR(dDate25, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' is: ' || numYear);
END;
```

Output:

> First year of the nearest century to 2016-01-27 is: 2001
>
> First year of the nearest century to 2116-01-27 is: 2101
>
> First year of the nearest century to 2051-01-27 is: 2101

`ROUND (TO_CHAR (dDate25, 'YYYY') / 100, 0) * 100` gives you the nearest century i.e. it would round 2055 up to 2100. Adding +1 gives you the first year of the nearest century.

You can then `TO_DATE(numYear || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to get January 1 of the first year of the nearest century if you need it in a date variable.